# Real-time form countdown timer with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

<sub>Pardon my grammar/spelling</sub>

So, I was [searching about how to make a countdown timer](http://jsfiddle.net/robbmj/Lzyxnaoq/2/) with javascript, but I want it to be in `<form>`, so when the user typed some numbers (which became the seconds), and then they click "Start", the timer will be started. But, I stuck in developing the script.

Here's the body:

```js
$('#detik').keyup(function() {
  var sec = $(this).val();
});

var display = document.querySelector('#time'),
  timer = new CountDownTimer(sec),
  timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(sec);
format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

timer.onTick(format);

$('#timerb').click(function() {
  timer.start();
});

function format(minutes, seconds) {
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/robbmj/simple-js-countdown-timer/master/countdowntimer.js"></script>


<div class="text-center">
  <h1 id="time"></h1>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <form id="formtimer" name="formtimer" class="form-inline" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="detik" placeholder="How many secs?">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="timerb">Start!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

What's wrong with my script? Why I can't show the **00:00**?

Comment: Where is this function `onclick="set()"`

Comment: @Tushar No, I'm not using it, I was thinking of merging those javascript into a `function set()` before.

Comment: Why not use a jQuery plugin to handle the countdown and just paste in it the correct time after submitting the form? There are many such plugins out there, [I've developed one myself](https://github.com/fiedlr/timeLeft)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#timerb').click(function() {
        var sec     = $("#detik").val();
        var timer   = new CountDownTimer(sec);
        var timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(sec);
        
        format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);
        timer.onTick(format);
        timer.start();
    });

    function format(minutes, seconds) {
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        
        var display = document.querySelector('#time');
        display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/robbmj/simple-js-countdown-timer/master/countdowntimer.js"></script>


<div class="text-center">
  <h1 id="time"></h1>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <form id="formtimer" name="formtimer" class="form-inline" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="detik" placeholder="How many secs?">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="timerb">Start!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```